# Stuck on proof of a martingale equality (similar to doob's inequality)

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

The question is: Let $M$ be a positive, continuous martingale that converges a.s. to zero as $t$ tends to inﬁnity. Prove that for every $x > 0$
$$P\{\sup_{t\geq 0} M_t > x \,| \,F_0\} = 1\wedge \frac{M_0}{x}$$
almost surely.

From Doob's martingale inequality we may conclude that $P\{\sup_{t\geq 0} M_t > x \,| \,F_0\} \leq 1\wedge \frac{M_0}{x}$, but right now I'm stuck on showing that
$$P\{\sup_{t\geq 0} M_t > x \,| \,F_0\} \geq 1\wedge \frac{M_0}{x}.$$
On this part I'm completely clueless right now. Any tips?

P.S. We were given the tip "stop the martingale when it gets above $x$", but I don't see what we can do with such a stopped martingale.